# Error using numpy.linspace() in jupyter, Python 3.x

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

**Using Python 3.x in Jupyter Notebook**

After importing pandas as pd and numpy as np
I have a df dataframe, which has a "Price" column, I want to use np.linspace() as follows:

```
bins = np.linspace(min(df["Price"]), max(df["Price"]), 3)
```

and i get *the following error:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a109ed9a4033> in <module>
      7 #numpy.linspace(valor-inicial, valor-final, número de valores)
      8 #https://www.interactivechaos.com/manual/tutorial-de-numpy/las-funciones-linspace-y-logspace
----> 9 bins = np.linspace(min(df["Precio"]), max(df["Precio"]), 3)
     10 
     11 #Creamos una lista "group_names" que contiene los diferentes nombres de bin

<__array_function__ internals> in linspace(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    127     # Convert float/complex array scalars to float, gh-3504
    128     # and make sure one can use variables that have an __array_interface__, gh-6634
--> 129     start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0
    130     stop  = asanyarray(stop)  * 1.0
    131 

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature 
matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: It sounds like your Price column contains strings, rather than numbers.

Comment: Show us a sample of the `df`, or at least the `Price` column.  Look at the `min(df['Price']`.  Does that make sense as a numeric range point?  The error says it's a string, not a number.

Comment: The problem was solved
thanks friends ... it happened that the Price column is of type "object", so
with function
df ["Price"] = df ["Price"]. astype ("int64")
I converted it to int64

Thanks a lot